# Swap name and content of a (lookup) vector in an one liner / library function

Tags: r

In my code I use lookup tables quite often, for example to have more verbose versions of column names in a data frame. For instance:

```
lkp <- c(speed = "Speed in mph", dist = "Stopping Distance in ft")
makePlot <- function(x = names(cars)) {
   x <- match.arg(x)
   hist(cars[[x]], xlab = lkp[[x]])
}
```

Now it happens that I want to reverse the lookup vector *[*]*, which is easily done by

```
setNames(names(lkp), lkp)
```

If `lkp` is a bit more complicated, this becomes quite a lot of typing:

```
setNames(names(c(firstLkp, secondLkp, thirdLkp, youGotTheIdea)),
         c(firstLkp, secondLkp, thirdLkp, youGotTheIdea))
```

with a lot of redundant code. Of course I could create a temporary variable

```
fullLkp <- c(firstLkp, secondLkp, thirdLkp, youGotTheIdea)
setNames(names(fullLkp), fullLkp)
```

Or even write a simple function doing it for me

```
swap_names_content <- function(x) setNames(names(x), x)
```

However, since this seems to me to be such a common task, I was wondering whether there is already a function in one of the popular packages doing the same?

---

*[*]* A common use case for me is the use of shiny's `selectInput` for instance:

> List of values to select from. If elements of the list are **named**, then that **name** rather than the value is displayed to the user.

That is, it is exactly the reverse of my typical lookup table.

Comment: why not using `lapply(listOfLkp, function(x) setNames(names(x), x))`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but this is not necessarily shorter and could lead to problems when moving from a `vector` to a `list`